# Missing label with PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to use `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` in order to obtain different types, but am always getting odd exception:

> Missing label for test_type

My entity:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class TestResult(
    @Json(name = "test_type") val testType: TestType,
    ...
    @Json(name = "session") val session: Session,
    ...
)
```

Here is my moshi factory:

```
val moshiFactory = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(
        PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Session::class.java, "test_type")
            .withSubtype(FirstSession::class.java, "first")
            .withSubtype(SecondSession::class.java, "second")
    )
    .build()
```

Structure of json response:

```
 {
   response: [ 
      test_type: "first",
      ...
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**test_type** must be a field of session class.

if the **test_type** can't be inside a session class, then you must declare a class for every variant of TestResult containing the specific Session class as follows:

```
sealed class TestResultSession(open val testType: String)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class TestResultFirstSession(
    @Json(name = "test_type") override val testType: String,
    @Json(name = "session") val session: FirstSession
) : TestResultSession(testType)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class TestResultSecondSession(
    @Json(name = "test_type") override val testType: String,
    @Json(name = "session") val session: SecondSession
) : TestResultSession(testType)
```

and your moshi polymorphic adapter:

```
val moshiFactory = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(
        PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(TestResultSession::class.java,"test_type")
            .withSubtype(TestResultFirstSession::class.java, "first")
            .withSubtype(TestResultSecondSession::class.java, "second")
    )
    .build()
```

it is always good practise to provide a fallback, so your deserialisation doesn't fail, in case **test_type** is unknown:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class FallbackTestResult(override val testType: String = "")  : TestResultSession(testType)

val moshiFactory = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(
        PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(TestResultSession::class.java,"test_type")
            .withSubtype(TestResultFirstSession::class.java, "first")
            .withSubtype(TestResultSecondSession::class.java, "second")
            .withDefaultValue(FallbackTestResult())

    )
    .build()
```